# Content delivery session times out in 1/2 minute with MongoDB session provider

Tags: session-state

We are using the MongoDB session state provider for our Sitecore 8.1 CD instance hosted in Azure web apps.

We are facing an issue with our CD instance where the session keeps expiring within 1–2 minutes. But the form authentication is still active. I.e. the user is still logged in, but can't access the session; therefore, the user can't proceed with page actions, e.g. submit form etc.

Below is our configurations for session and forms:

```xml
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="mongo" cookieless="false" timeout="30" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager">
  <providers>
    <add name="mongo" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
    <!-- <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" /> -->
  </providers>
</sessionState>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/login" requireSSL="false" name=".ASPXAUTH" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" path="/" timeout="120" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

Note that we share the same session collection/db between test and uat environments.

1. If I change the mode to 'InProc', the issue goes away.
2. As suggested by Dymtro, we stood up separate collections for session
   and analytics. The issue still persists.
3. What's the best way to troubleshoot why/how sitecore is identifying real users as bots?
4. The session time out doesn't occur on our test environment where we haven't implemented this below:

> ```
> @using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions
> @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()
> ```

Comment: Forms authentication doesn't actually require session state as all the data travels in the cookie, so there's no correlation between Forms Auth working or timing out and Session State working or timing out.

Comment: Further to the above thought, submitting forms / page actions don't specifically require session either.  When you say "can't access the session", are you getting a specific error when reading? writing? do you observe the sessions being removed from the database (that's what the Mongo Session provider will do every "pollingInterval")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe robot detection is related to your problem. As you correctly suggested in the comments, changing session state provider should not affect robot functionality and the way it overrides session timeout.

## Hypothesis

This may be the root of your problem:

> Note that we share the same session collection/db between test and uat environments.

The private session store is not supposed to be shared between unrelated instances. The biggest reason for that is the fact that only one instance will be able to handle the `Session_End` event from the store. If it's not the instance that actually *created* the session, there will be errors (check your logs on both instances).

*Note that this is not a problem with non-sticky load-balanced instances of the same cluster, as all of them are equal. It's only a problem with instances that share the private session and don't share other things, such as the web database, the Shared Session state store, Sitecore configuration, etc. I.e. instances that are not part of the same [**CD cluster**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/clustered_server_environments).*

Another problem with sharing the private session state is if Sitecore instances don't have matching date/time settings. In that case, one instance will create a session, and another instance may think the session has already expired, so it will remove session data from the store and attempt to process the `Session_End` event.

## Solution

Create a separate session database/collection corresponding to each of your Sitecore instances.

In the future, never share one store between multiple Sitecore instances, unless they have exactly the same configuration and belong to the same content delivery cluster.

Comment: We stood up separate databases for session and rest of analytics for UAT. The time out issue still persists.

Comment: @NilPun Then my hypothesis must be wrong, and it is indeed the robot detection that overrides your session timeout. The strange thing, of course, is that this doesn't happen with `InProc`. In any case, please follow the advice from Mark to make sure your visitors are not handled as robots.

Comment: Confusing. It works with out MVC visitor Identification on Test environment with mongo session providers. Not really sure what's causing this issue.

Comment: @NilPun are there configuration differences between Test and UAT?

Comment: Yep they are same except connection string

Answer (score 8):

I think your sessions are being flagged as "robot". The most common cause for this, is forgetting to include `VisitorIdentification` on your main layout or main View file.

Webforms:

`<sc:VisitorIdentification runat='server'/>`

MVC:

```razor
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions
@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()
```

Additional info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626563/sitecore-7-5-mvc-and-httpcontext-session-timeout-set-to-1-min

EDIT: **updated to include the following**

The easiest way to assert whether it is indeed robot detection that is the root cause, is to disable the automatic robot detection. There is a hidden setting that can toggle this functionality on and off.

`<setting name="Analytics.AutoDetectBots" value="false" />`

Default value is true. Try adding this to your configs as `false` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: This sounds like the probable cause. I have seen this happen several times when the layout does not have the visitor identification.

Comment: hi Mark,  if it's related to bot identification, any reason why it works if I change the mode to 'InProc'?

Comment: There could be any number of reasons; the bot detection code is very involved. Try disabling bot detection entirely as described in my edit above and see if the problem goes away. Would prove/disprove if we are on the right track at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening due to the fact that the session is being identified as a robot.

**EDIT 1**
You need to solve the issue why the user is being identified as a robot. As an workaround, you may try the follow:

Increase the Session timeout from the Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config file. It is found in the App_Config/Include folder.

Search for the Analytics.Robots.SessionTimeout and update the value.

**EDIT 2**
The sharedsession will get expired after one minute as provided in the Sitecore Documentation. Please see the diagram below:

[image: sessionstate]

For more info, please check [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/session_state/session_state)

**EDIT 3**
Robot detection classifies a contact based on IP address, Geo IP information, and user agent.

Robot detection relies on two heuristics to identify robots:

- A browser that does not carry cookies between requests.
- A browser that does not support JavaScript or does not raise any mouse or touch events.

You can have more info at those links from Sitecore Official Documentation

1: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/contacts/contact_tracking

2: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/robot_detection/configure_the_robot_detection_component

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make sure the visitor is not identified as a robot instead of extending all robot sessions?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: If it's related to bot identification, any reason why it works if I change the mode to 'InProc'?

Comment: InProc is the default sessionstate which is private and stored in memory. Please see updated answer at Edit 2

Comment: What's the best way to troubleshoot why/how sitecore is identifying real users as bots?

Comment: Please find the EDIT 3 of the answer. I have just updated it